# Android caffe built demo shows error

Tags: android, android-ndk, caffe

Being new to [Android NDK Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/), I would like to use built version in my Android project. I tried to run [this built sample demo](https://github.com/sh1r0/caffe-android-demo), but while running, it showed the following:

```
 03-26 14:46:35.697    2800-3042/com.sh1r0.caffe_android_demo A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 3042 (AsyncTask #1)
```

(the app crashed)

Comment: You're dereferencing a null pointer in C code.  Find the stack trace in there and you can figure out what function it was in.  Other than that there's not much we can do to help you, you don't give us any information.

Comment: do u mean about `Logcat`?

Comment: It'll probably be in your logcat (but might not be, some devices route C crashes to traces.txt).  It will have a different format though as its a C partial core dump, not a java stack trace.

Comment: If possible please download and run the demo application and let me know whether you too getting the same error or not.plz

Answer (score 1):

I can see that the sigsev signal is thrown through android AsyncTask.
The problem could come from this function.

```
caffeMobile.predictImage(strings[0])[0]; //line 160 of MainActivity
```

This signal comes from JNI and it is very difficult to know where is the problem unless you can debug natively (through ndk) the app. The caffe-sample is not configured to debug on native method.

Try this issues to manage the error:

> Ensure that your image path in this string[0] arrays are not empty. and exists.
>
> Ensure that the other caffeMobile functions are able to exec without
>   problems, for example:

```
  caffeMobile = new CaffeMobile();
  caffeMobile.setNumThreads(4);
  caffeMobile.loadModel("/sdcard/caffe_mobile/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt",    "/sdcard/caffe_mobile/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel");
```

If you are able to execute the other functions, probably your image path is not correct, check.

If you are not able to execute loadModel or setNumThreads function, probably the apk is not loading libjni.so library correctly , or the jni bridge is not able to locate jni functions.